# Integrating Spring Cloud Data Flow for existing Spring Batch application

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have an exiting Spring Batch application, with a Job. I would like to monitor the Job, using Spring Cloud Data Flow. How can we integrate Spring Cloud Data Flow with my existing spring batch application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a Spring Batch Job as a Task in SCDF is straightforward. All you'd have to do is to wrap the batch-job in Spring Could Task programming model and register it in SCDF. You can use the batch-job [sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/master/spring-cloud-task-samples/batch-job) for reference.

Here's a full-blown [file-ingest use-case](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_batch_file_ingest) running as a Task in SCDF.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It Helped me a lot. And iam trying to achieve the below things with Spring Batch and SCDF,

Comment: I have my batch application connected to a MYSQL DB which need to be monitored. currently Jobs, Start time and end time is not getting populated. Do we need any other configuration for that?

Comment: And one more thing is am having two methods exposed as a Rest API, which starts different Jobs when fired. So i need to create two different
Task, which can be started, monitored separtely from SCDF. How can we do that?
Then if i start my Jobs by firing the api, i need that job also to be monitored in SCDF. How can we do that?
Thanks in Advance:) Sorry for too many question:(

Comment: @Sabby Anandan - Could you please reply to above query ?